# \let a control sequence to a redefined primitive

Tags: pdftex, primitives

pdfTeX version 1.40.0 introduced the primitive `\pdfprimitive` which the manual describes as follows.

> This command executes the primitive meaning of the following control sequence, if it has been redeﬁned 
>   or made undeﬁned. If the following control sequence is undeﬁned and never was a primitive, nothing 
>   happens and no error is raised. If the control sequence was initially expandable, `\pdfprimitive` expands 
>   either. Otherwise `\pdfprimitive` doesn’t expand.

(I think “either” should be “too.”)

**Is there a way to `\let` a control sequence to the primitive version?** Something like

```
\let\input\relax
\pdfletprimitive\input\input
```

The idea being that `\input` could be restored to its original meaning (at least locally). Obviously

```
\let\input\pdfprimitive\input
```

is not going to work just as

```
\expandafter\let\expandafter\input\pdfprimitive\input
```

is not going to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, I'm afraid not. When you `\let` or `\def` the original definition of primitive to something, the original meaning is no longer available as an accessible token. `\pdfprimitive` can be used to access the internal definition of the primitive, but that is not the same as 'regenerating' the accessible token. The nearest you can get is

```
\def\<primitive>{\pdfprimitive\<primitive>}
```

for expandable primitives or

```
\protected\def\<primitive>{\pdfprimitive\<primitive>}
```

for non-expandable ones.

Comment: And it would seem that that doesn't work for `\endcsname`. My use case was fairly ridiculous anyway, so it's not like this is a show stopper. =) Thanks.